# Jumping ImageView while dragging. getX() and getY() values are jumping

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I've created an onTouchListener for dragging Views. Images drag smoothly if I use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`. The problem with that is the image will jump to the second pointer when you place a second pointer down then lift the first pointer.

This onTouchListener attempts to fix that issue by keeping track of the `pointerId`. The problem with this onTouchListener is while dragging an ImageView, the ImageView jumps around pretty crazily. The `getX()` and `getY()` values jump around.

I feel like I'm doing this correctly. I don't want to have to write a custom view for this because I've already implemented a scaleGestureDetector and written a custom rotateGestureDetector that work. Everything works fine but I need to fix the issue I get when using `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my onTouchListener:

```
final View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        relativeLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();

                // Where the user started the drag
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
                activePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                // Where the user's finger is during the drag
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(activePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Calculate change in x and change in y
                final float dx = x - lastX;
                final float dy = y - lastY;

                // Update the margins to move the view
                relativeLayoutParams.leftMargin += dx;
                relativeLayoutParams.topMargin += dy;
                v.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

                // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;

                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                activePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            {
                activePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            {
                // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                if(pointerId == activePointerId)
                {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    lastX = (int) event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    lastY = (int) event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    activePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
image1.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

Comment: Anybody have a solution to this? Seems like others have run into this issue, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was simple, but unexpected. `getRawX/Y()` returns absolute coordinates, while `getX/Y()` returns coordinates relative to the view. I would move the view, reset `lastX/Y`, and the image wouldn't be in the same spot anymore so when I get new values they'd be off. In this case I only needed where I **originally** pressed the image (not the case when using `getRawX/Y').

So, the solution was to simply remove the following:

```
// Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
lastX = x;
lastY = y;
```

I hope this will help somebody in the future, because I've seen others with this problem, and they had similar code to me (resetting `lastX/Y`)

Comment: Glad I found this! I suspect many people have code for saving the lastX/LastY because of reading http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html . Apparently the situation of moving a view differs from the example in "multitouch" where a canvas is being translated. The last comment here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676097/android-getx-gety-interleaves-relative-absolute-coordinates?rq=1, notes that when he commented out the setting of view.setX() and view.setY(), the interleaving of absolute and relative coordinates during onTouch() stopped.

Comment: @T.Folsom Glad I could help! Yes, a lot of people model their code after your first link, myself included. As far as I know, `getX()` and `getY()` always return relative coordinates. His coordinates were jumping for the same reason as me. He moves the view then gets different relative coordinates because the view has shifted. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, this did help more people :)

Comment: 2019, still helpful. I've got the sample code from the official docs (https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale) and inherited this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Vasiliy Wonderful :) I’m glad the answer has held up

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I found this to be the issue, getRawX is absolute and getX is relative to view. hence use this to transform one to another

```
//RawX = getX + View.getX

event.getRawX == event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1))+view.getX()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have One tip & think it will help.

```
invalidate() : does only redrawing a view,doesn't change view size/position.
```

What you should use is
`requestLayout()`: does the measuring and layout process. & i think `requestLayout()` will be called when call `setLayoutParams()`;

So Try by removing `v.invalidate()`

or try using `view.layout(left,top,right,bottom)` method instead of setting layoutParams.

Comment: I've tried removing `v.invalidate()` in the past (tried it again just now since you suggested it) since I figured it's useless in this scenario, doesn't help though. I tried replacing it with `v.requestLayout()` and that didn't change the behavior either :/ Any other suggestions?

Comment: or try using view.layout(left,top,right,bottom) method instead of setting layoutParams.